# how to make objects using an index number

Tags: c#, object, indexing

I want to make my program that i made way shorter then it is right now.
I make 8 different objects and do things with them but I want to make it with something like a for loop and an index number.
Is there a way to do this, because i've looked it up but don't seem to find anything.

The objects and such are in Dutch sorry for that.

```
private void AankomstButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (welkKind == 1)
        {
            if (File.Exists(@"Bestanden/" + kind1.Naam + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("Y") + ".txt") == false)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"Bestanden/" + kind2.Naam + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("Y") + ".txt")) ;

            }
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"Bestanden/" + kind2.Naam + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("Y") + ".txt"))
                {

                    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("d") + " Aangekomen: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("t"));
                }                   

            }
        }


        if (welkKind == 2)
        {
            if (File.Exists(@"Bestanden/" + kind2.Naam + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("Y") + ".txt"))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"Bestanden/" + kind2.Naam + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("Y") + ".txt"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("d") + " Aangekomen: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("t"));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"Bestanden/" + kind2.Naam + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("Y") + ".txt"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("d") + " Aangekomen: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("t"));
                }
            }
        }
        if (welkKind == 3)
        {
            if (File.Exists(@"Bestanden/" + kind3.Naam + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("Y") + ".txt"))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"Bestanden/" + kind3.Naam + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("Y") + ".txt"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("d") + " Aangekomen: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("t"));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"Bestanden/" + kind3.Naam + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("Y") + ".txt"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("d") + " Aangekomen: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("t"));
                }
            }
        }
        if (welkKind == 4)
        {
            if (File.Exists(@"Bestanden/" + kind4.Naam + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("Y") + ".txt"))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"Bestanden/" + kind4.Naam + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("Y") + ".txt"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("d") + " Aangekomen: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("t"));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"Bestanden/" + kind4.Naam + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("Y") + ".txt"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("d") + " Aangekomen: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("t"));
                }
            }
        }
        if (welkKind == 5)
        {
            if (File.Exists(@"Bestanden/" + kind5.Naam + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("Y") + ".txt"))
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(@"Bestanden/" + kind5.Naam + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("Y") + ".txt"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("d") + " Aangekomen: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("t"));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"Bestanden/" + kind5.Naam + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("Y") + ".txt"))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("d") + " Aangekomen: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("t"));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is kind2.naam? Is it a resource or property of a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep an array of children (`kind`), you can access the array by index.

```
Kind[] children = new Kind[] { kind1, kind2 };

if (welkKind >= 0 && welkKind < children.Length)
{
    Kind kind = children[welkKind];

    string fileName = @"Bestanden/" + kind.Naam + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("Y") + ".txt";
    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("d") + " Aangekomen: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("t"));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(fileName))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("d") + " Aangekomen: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("t"));
        }
    }
}
```

Another option would be a list, which would have similar syntax in its usage, but you can dynamically add and remove items from the list:

```
List<Kind> children = new List<Kind>();
children.Add(kind1);
children.Add(kind2);
children.Add(new Kind() { Naam = "John" });

if (welkKind >= 0 && welkKind < children.Count)
{
    Kind kind = children[welkKind];
}
```

Comment: If you have similar instances used for similar purposes in your code, it is almost certainly better to hold them in some sort of collection rather than having individual variables (kind1, kind2, etc.).

Comment: Of course, but those variables are there now, so he has to add then at some place.

Comment: I'm agreeing with your solution.  The refactoring needs to be done also for the variables, not only in the method.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've only recently learned how to work with objects and such, so this helped me a lot, I will keep this in my head now!